# Cannot connect to 192.168.1.1 TP-Link router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I just moved to a new apartment and want to configure my router. I can ping 192.168.1.1 and I'm connected to the desired network. I scanned ports on 192.168.1.1 and there's no 80 port open. I have full access to the Internet.

The problem is that I don't have the password for the WiFi and I cannot contact the previous tenant either. I don't want to reset the router, because its MAC might be cloned and if I lose it I'll be in trouble. The exact version of the router is a TP-Link WR740N - it says on the sticker on the back of the router that I should be able to access tplinkwifi.net, but it's not hosted either.

**UPDATE:** as advised by Kamil Maciorowski, I sniffed packets coming from the router and tried to change the MAC address of the PC (I'm running Windows 7) and used "Win7 MAC address Changer" to do it.

**UPDATE:** I just found that the previous tenant for some unknown reason installed openwrt I just connected to the root and it's all fine for now. This all happened by accident :D

Comment: Are you sure 192.168.1.1 is the router? Is that the default gateway you were assigned by the DHCP server? I've seen networks where the router was .254 and the DHCP range started at 1. Also, .1 may be a wired modem/router with the wireless router having a different address.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I scanned the whole subnet there are only two hosts alive (I used nmap -Pn).

Comment: Did you obey "Win7 MAC Address Changer" when it said "Please disable and enable the network adapter for changes to take effect"?

Comment: Yes I disabled and enabled, actually I sniffed packets after that too and the mac was indeed changed so it can't be the issue

Answer (score 1):

First simple step: connect your computer to ISP cable directly, without a router (good idea is to have a software firewall enabled in your OS). Maybe there is no *MAC* filtering at all and you will gain network access. In that case you can reset your router to defaults.

#### Finding *MAC address* of the router WAN interface

Install a sniffer (e.g. *Wireshark*) on your computer and learn how to capture packets in promiscuous mode. Learn how to examine packets and see *MAC addresses* they carry. Learn how to filter traffic to see incoming packets only. You can learn with your current network setup.

---

Our example, *Wireshark*, has [Packet Details](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUsePacketDetailsPaneSection.html) pane. The line like

`Ethernet II, Src:` (...) `(aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff)` (...) `(00:11:22:33:44:55)`

contains source and destination *MAC*s for the packet.

---

Turn your router off, disconnect all network cables. Connect your computer to the WAN (blue) interface with a cable. Setup the sniffing program to capture incoming packets. Turn your router on and wait.

If the router is set to obtain its *WAN IP configuration* from *DHCP server*, you will see *DHCP Discover* packet. Source *MAC address* in that packet is your router *MAC address*.

Lack of *DHCP Discover* packet indicates that the router has *fixed IP* setup. There may be other packets sniffed and you may be able to read the *MAC address* and the *IP address* from them. To make the router generate some packets connect another computer to its LAN port and try to reach a host in the Internet (e.g. `8.8.8.8` or `superuser.com`). You will fail of course, but your sniffing computer will receive few TCP/IP packets.

Having *MAC address*, the wise thing to do is to clone it on another router or your computer (google for solution that works in your OS). Connect the device with cloned *MAC* directly to ISP and make sure you get valid network setup and you can use the Internet. The aim of this step is to rule out the (extremely rare) situation where there is no *DHCP server* provided by ISP and the whole network works with fixed addresses.

---

## EDIT:

Connecting from your computer (with cloned *MAC*) directly to ISP may fail if neither your network card nor the hardware at the other end of the link support [*Auto MDI-X*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface#Auto_MDI-X) technology and you connect to a [*crossover cable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable). By the book there should be a *straight through cable* allowing to connect a computer to a network device like router, but someone may have made a mistake. Your router can work with either type of cable thanks to *Auto MDI-X* – nowadays practically all home routers can, so users don't need to bother. There are, however, specialized routers and switches without *Auto MDI-X* support; one of them may be on the other side of the cable.

Try sniffing the traffic when you connect directly to ISP (with cloned *MAC*). If there is at least one valid incoming packet, then *MDI-X* is not a problem.

*(Edit ends here.)*

---

**If everything is fine**, then the *MAC address* is all you need and **you can reset your router to defaults (and the rest of my answer may be skipped).** Otherwise you need to know correct *IP*, *netmask* and *gateway* to use as a fixed setup.

Below quick hints on what to do in such case. They do not cover details and require some knowledge/research in the networking field. There may be other methods as well.

---

#### Finding fixed *IP address* of the router WAN interface

Make the router generate some TCP/IP packets as described above, analyze with a sniffer to learn their *source IP*.

#### Finding fixed *gateway* of the router WAN interface

Connect to Internet via the router (as normal, no sniffing nor other tricks). Use `tracert` or `traceroute` (depends on OS) to some external address (say `superuser.com`). The first IP after your router LAN IP should be the gateway on the WAN side, unless the list ends at this position and it is the address you query (I doubt your router has direct connection to `superuser.com` but in a general case it might). Try several addresses to make sure.

#### Finding fixed *netmask* of the router WAN interface

1. Find the *narrowest netmask* that makes your router *IP* and *gateway* be in the same subnet. That *narrowest netmask* should work for vast majority of connections and you may never need a broader one; don't stop now, though.
2. You can take an educated guess on the *netmask* by sniffing on ISP cable. You may find local traffic between another routers/computers; their *IP*s may give hints how broad the subnet is. Your *narrowest netmask* estimation may go broader now.
3. Connect to your router on its WAN interface and sniff the network trafic. Set your computer to *gateway* IP with broadest *netmask* possible (try <strike>`127`</strike>`128.0.0.0`). Use another device on the LAN side and try to reach *IP addresses* that may or may not be inside the subnet on the WAN side. Start with *gateway* IP. Query IPs sequentially that the next one requires a bit broader subnet than the previous one. The sniffed packets from the router (on the WAN side) will be destined to the gateway (i.e. your sniffing computer) by its *MAC address* if the target IP is outside the router subnet; if the target IP is inside the router subnet, then the router will try to find it there and the pattern will be different. This way you can find the *netmask* your router uses.

#### What about *DNS servers* in fixed setup?

DNS server adresses the router uses may be obtained by sniffing WAN interface as a fake gateway while a second computer (from the LAN side) queries various URLs. Look for packets destined to port `53`; refer to how DNS works for details.

You may also try to use real *gateway* as *DNS server*, it may or may not work. Or you can use *Google Public DNS* (`8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4`) or *OpenDNS* (`208.67.222.222`, `208.67.220.220`). Your ISP shouldn't block these addresses.

Comment: Thanks that's great idea, I'll try it soon and post the result.

Comment: I got the mac address of the router, but as it turns out it's not the cloned one, but its own. When I try to change my mac and connect to network without router, the network was not identified.

Comment: Was there *DHCP Discover* packet from the router when you were sniffing?

Comment: Yes, I sniffed it using Wireshark

Comment: You said "it's not the cloned one, but its own". Does it mean it matches the sticker or something? Maybe it was not supposed to be changed and "its own" is the right one. Frankly, I don't know why the network rejected your computer with cloned *MAC*. Either there is something beyond my experiences here, or your cloning attempt was somewhat faulty. I recommend you edit your question and add information that you sniffed, discovered the *MAC* but couldn't connect with another hardware after cloning. Write what you did exactly to clone the *MAC*.

Comment: The only thing that bugs me is that, is it possible that it's used as access point not as router? As I said i just moved to my apartment I have no idea where the cable comes from

Comment: @JukesOnYou I edited my answer. There is *MDI-X* pitfall. Give feedback: can you sniff incoming packet(s) when you connect your PC directly to ISP?

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a bit confusing. A bit more information is needed.

The router has not been yours before?

So the router has 192.168.1.1, and your computer does actually connect to the internet. Are you using a cable?

Does your computer have a static IP address, or did the router serve one?

Anyway, try this:

- Totally disconnect the router
- Turn it off and on again
- Connect your computer (with network address setting for DHCP, just in case)
- Check if you receive an IP address
- Ping and scan tplinkwifi.net (with the router disconnected from your internet uplink, this should resolve to the router's address, which will typically be 192.168.1.1).

Comment: No, router was not mine. I moved to apartment (provided by employer). As it turns out they don't have any information about router. So router belonged to the previous tenant, who I cannot contact to. The ip was provided by router and yes I'm using LAN. When I tried to ping tplinkwifi.net it cannot be reached. Thanks for your replay!

Comment: The router's settings may have been massively changed, and once you're connected to the web interface you might find that you have no admin password, which would present the next problem. You may try to scan the whole device in case the admin interface is listening on another port than 80 - but, quite frankly, I'd hard-reset the whole thing.

Comment: I'm too scared to reset, because its mac is cloned and I'm gonna lose if I reset it